# Use JsonInclude annotation to ignore empty values in a extended class

Tags: java, json, jackson

Java 1.8, Jackson library 2.1.5

I need to override the behaviour of how an object is serialized in json.

What i need is to ignore the `bonus` property from the serialized json response in case the value is null and the employee is a `Partner` employee. However trying the code below does not seem to work as expected.

```
class Employee{
    private String bonus;
    public String getBonus(){return bonus;}
    public String setBonus(){this.bonus = bonus;}
}

class Partner extends Employee{
    @Override
    @JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
    public String getBonus(){return super.getBonus();}
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get by with excluding all `null` properties, then you can use the `@JsonSerialize` on the class. The following test runs successfully for me using Jackson 2.1.5:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SomeTest {
    public static class Employee {
        private String bonus;

        public String getBonus() {
            return bonus;
        }

        public void setBonus(String bonus) {
            this.bonus = bonus;
        }
    }

    @JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
    public static class Partner extends Employee {
        @Override
        public String getBonus() {
            return super.getBonus();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSerialize() throws Exception {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        Partner partner = new Partner();

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println("Employee: " + objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employee));
        System.out.println(" Partner: " + objectMapper.writeValueAsString(partner));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Employee: {"bonus":null}
 Partner: {}
```

Comment: What version of Jackson are you using? Have you tried `objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)`? That will exclude all `null` properties.

Comment: Jackson library 2.1.5. I cannot use the ObjectMapper since i am not the endpoint

Comment: thanks erik, it seems that for some other reason my code doesn't work as expected. I accept your answer

Comment: Just a guess, but if you don't have control over the ObjectMapper configuration, I wonder if it has something to do with that.